# Microsoft Apps Not Saving

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, adobe-indesign

I have a Mac running Catalina that all of the sudden will try to save every file including word, excel and indesign as SAVE AS and not SAVE when I click SAVE. Even though Im working on an existing document.
Has anyone run into this issue before?
Any assistance is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check permissions on the location you are trying to save to & also on the [originals of] files you are trying to save.

Comment: Where did you open Office files? If you have no permission to write the files, you cannot save directly but instead of "save as".